# HAProxy 1.5 - Using a map to link paths to backend

Tags: url, proxy, configuration, haproxy

Basically, as the title suggests.  I'm trying to simplify my HAProxy configuration file, and found out about the `map` function.  Right now, I'm trying to set it up to match a path to a particular backend.  The original setup for the file looked like this:

```
#This is a cleaned up version, as I'm not comfortable putting actual paths and server names online
#That said, this is the same basic format

frontend http
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:5110

  acl employee-webserver path_reg -i /test/employee/.* 
  use_backend servers-employee-webserver if employee-webserver 

  acl employee-internal_api path_reg -i /test/internal_api/employee/.* 
  use_backend servers-employee-internal_api if employee-internal_api

backend servers-employee-webserver 
  balance leastconn
  cookie TEST insert 
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  server server1.test.com 127.0.0.1:9000 cookie S1 check inter 30s fall 1 rise 1 

backend servers-employee-internal_api 
  balance leastconn  
  cookie TEST insert
  reqrep ^(.+)\ /test/internal_api/employee/(.*?$) \1\ /\2
  server server1.test.com 127.0.0.1:8000 cookie S1 check inter 30s fall 1 rise 1
```

The service in question has multiple parts, a webserver that the client uses, and an internal API.  We also have other services that use this same setup, and would be in this file.

I found out that I can use a map file to simplify this, extracting the paths and the names of the corresponding backends into a separate file:

```
frontend http
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:5110

  use_backend bk_%[base,map_beg(/apps/haproxy/config/haproxy.map)]

backend servers-employee-webserver 
  balance leastconn
  cookie TEST insert 
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  server server1.test.com 127.0.0.1:9000 cookie S1 check inter 30s fall 1 rise 1 

backend servers-employee-internal_api 
  balance leastconn  
  cookie TEST insert
  reqrep ^(.+)\ /test/internal_api/employee/(.*?$) \1\ /\2
  server server1.test.com 127.0.0.1:8000 cookie S1 check inter 30s fall 1 rise 1
```

Where the map file, haproxy.map, is:

```
server1.test.com:5110/test/employee servers-employee-webserver
server1.test.com:5110/test/internal_api/employee servers-employee-internal_api
```

However, I'm still getting a 503 error when going to `server1.test.com:5110/test/employee/home`, when my understanding is that the key `server1.test.com:5110/test/employee` should consider that as a valid mapping.  I've tried removing the server name so I only have the path, I've tried including the protocol (http), and I've tried adding a wildcard at the end of the path.  None of these have had any affect.

1. What am I doing wrong with my map file?  Is this even a capability of haproxy 1.5?
2. If I can get this to work properly, I will be hosting the haproxy instance behind a DNS, `employee_service.company.com`, which will point to haproxy on port 5110.  I'm assuming I'll have to replace the server name in the map file with the DNS name one that is finished.  Is that correct?
3. Is it possible to do a similar setup for the backends in using a mapping file, given that each needs a cookie, a X-Forwarded Proto header, and has a different regrep?

Comment: try to remove the `bk_` prefix in the use_backend keywork. if this isn't enough you can also log `%[base]` and see how haproxy is building this sample for your requests; 2. you need to change the dns part or use the `path` fetch sample; 3. please elaborate a bit more with an example.